# Where can I find pending Friend Invitations on Steam?

Tags: steam

One of the little cousins at our Christmas gatherings wanted to be friends on Steam. That's cool, but our first attempt at searching for his Steam username was a disaster, and we probably both wound up sending friend requests to total strangers.

This situation brought to light the "All Friends" page in the Steam web app.

Currently, I have two confirmed friends. And two friend invitations are still pending. The "All Friends" page says I have four friends. Clicking the "Manage Friends List" does not reveal anything extra.

**Where can I view pending friend invitations?**
**Is there any way to manage them, or cancel the invitation?**

*(or must I forever live with several imaginary friends...)*

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to see pending invitations in the friends list window. This is a different and separate window from the main Steam client window. You can view it by using the Friends -> View Friend List menu option from the Steam client window or by right clicking either the Steam icon in the notification area or the Steam button in the task bar and selecting Friends.

[image: Steam Friends List Window with pending invite]

You can cancel an invitation by right clicking on it and selecting Remove this Friend.

This must be done using the Steam desktop client. (This window is not available in the web app.)